# Debugging URLSession (in iOS 10)

Tags: ios, logging, nsurlsession, ios10

I am having trouble with a `URLSession` that creates and resumes a `URLSessionDataTask` in the sense that I expect subsequent calls to certain methods in the session's (and task`s) delegate but apparently no such calls occur.

How can I debug `URLSession` in a situation like this? For instance, can I request log output from it e.g. to find out when it sends or receives HTTP traffic or when it attempts to call a method in the delegate but cannot find the relevant implementation (e.g. because the method signature in the implementation may be slightly off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate methods are now (starting to be) called as expected. The solution consisted in copying method signatures from the very code base of `URLSessionDataDelegate` and `URLSessionTaskDelegate` (not their documentation) to ensure exact matches. Looking at device log output (lines with marked `libsystem_network.dylib` and `<Debug>`) was also helpful. The employed methods signatures are now as follows:

```
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                       task: URLSessionTask, 
                       didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                       completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void) {
  // ...
}

public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                       dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, 
                       didReceive data: Data) {
  // ...
}

public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                       task: URLSessionTask, 
                       didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
  // ...
}
```